# Share values between processes started by supervisord

Tags: linux, shell, supervisord

I have several shell scripts which are started by supervisord at startup, each one with its conf file.

I wrote a shell script which pre-calculates some simple values once, stores them in env vars.

What I need to achieve with supervisord is to run the pre-calculation script once, and then start the other scripts which read the env vars. What is the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scripts needing these env variables are launched by supervisord, then supervisord must create the environment for these scripts.

Thus, the one script which calculates the variables need to tell supervisord to create the variables and assign them values. The environment (env vars) is private to a process; the process can export the environment to its children, but not to other processes - especially not the father.

I don't know if there is a way to tell supervisord to modify the environment. Alternatively, each script can read its environment from somewhere else, for example they can *source* a file created by the pre-calculator script.